# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm writing tests for an API using [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest) and [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest). The first test passes as expected but all the tests that follow fail with the following error:

*Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.*

My test suite looks like this:

```
const app = require('../../index.js');
const request = require('supertest');
const faker = require('faker');
const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

const agent = request.agent(app);
const { truncateDatabase } = require('./helpers/truncateDatabase');

beforeEach(async (done) => {
    app.on("serverStarted", () => {
        done(); // Wait for tests to run until the server has started
    });
});

afterEach(async () => {
    await truncateDatabase();
});

describe('The register route', () => {
    it('Can run a happy flow and register a user', async (done) => {
        const firstname = faker.name.firstName();
        const lastname = faker.name.lastName();

        return agent.post('/register')
            .send({ firstname, lastname })
            .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
            .then((response) => {
                expect(response.body.message).toHaveProperty('firstname', firstname);
                expect(response.body.message).toHaveProperty('lastnamename', lastname);
                done();
            });
    });

    it('Can run a second test', async () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The first test takes an average of 500ms to complete, while the second test takes more than 5000ms. Thus throwing the timeout exception.

I have tried changing the request call by using async / await, like so:

```
const res = await agent.post('/v1/auth/register')
    .send({ firstname, lastname });
```

However, this did not solve the issue. Further things I've tried are:

- Passing a third argument to the `it` function,
- Increasing the timeout using `jest.setTimeout(10000)`,
- Calling `done` with the async / await version,
- Called `.end()` at the end of the request,
- Add `--runInBand --detectOpenHandles` to the jest test command,
- Removed the `describe` wrapper from the `it` functions.

None of the above seemed to help, what can I do solve this issue? And more importantly, why is this happening?

Sidenotes: the API is using [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) as ORM with a separate test database. The `/register` endpoint is not evoked twice (I've tested it by placing a console.log() in the original code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async`, raw promises and `done` shouldn't be mixed together in tests, this results in error-prone code. Promises are often left unchained. `done` is often used carelessly,  doesn't handle errors and results in test timeout if it's unreachable.

Since second test is a no-op and cannot timeout by itself, it's `beforeEach` to blame. If there's only one application instance, it's not expected to trigger `serverStarted` multiple times. The way how `serverStarted` works wasn't shown.

If the intention is to keep instances separately, it should be reinitialized for every test:

```
let app, agent;

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    app = require('../../index.js');
    agent = request.agent(app);
});

beforeEach((done) => {
    app.on("serverStarted", () => {
        // probably needs to handle errors
        done();
    });
});
```